# TailwindCSS styling not applied when passing prop value and using it in template literals (with Typescript)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have a `PrimaryButton` component in NextJS, where I'm using TailwindCSS for styling. The component accepts a size prop, and I'm encountering an issue where the styling doesn't apply correctly when I pass the size value from the prop and use it within template literals. However, when I check the console, it shows that the relevant CSS attribute is applied to the element, but visually it doesn't reflect the expected styling.

`PrimaryButton.tsx`

```js
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";

type Props = {
  size: number;
};

export default function PrimaryButton({ size }: Props) {

  const textSize = size ? `text-[${size.toString()}px]` : "";

  // Styling
  const primaryBtnStyle = `text-white p-2 bg-gradient-to-r from-indigo-400 to-rose-400 rounded-3xl ${textSize}`;

  return (
    <>
      <Link href="/signup" className={primaryBtnStyle}>
        Signup
      </Link>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Using component**

```js
 <PrimaryButton size={24} />
```

**Console Output**
[image: Console Output]

Is there anything I'm missing here. Any help would appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tailwind searches your source code for **complete class names** so it knows what CSS it needs to generate. This means that you cannot dynamically concatenate strings together to form a single class name, although you can concatenate multiple full class names together.

According to the [documentation](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#dynamic-class-names):

> The most important implication of how Tailwind extracts class names is that it will only find classes that exist as complete unbroken strings in your source files. 
>  If you use string interpolation or concatenate partial class names together, Tailwind will not find them and therefore will not generate the corresponding CSS

Consider using a fixed number of classes that can be represented in a static object or using inline styles.